# Android Studio - FileInputStream not working - File not found Exeception - Google Auth for Speech to text

Tags: java, android, fileinputstream, google-cloud-speech

I trying to load a JSON File which is needed by the Google Speech to Text API to auth the Client.
I have to pass the PATH of the JSON with the Credidentals, but if i try i get:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: com/THAB/TRH7APP/key.json (No such file or directory)`

The key.json file is in the same folder as the Activity File.

src/main/java/com/THAB/TRH7APP/key.json this is the path of the json File from the content root.
src/main/java/com/THAB/TRH7APP/MainActivity.java this is path from the java file.

I added the following permissions already to the Manifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I use a Pixel3 with API28 (Android 9)(Emulator). I tried every combination for the path, but it didn't work. Where i've to place the file or how i've to set the path? Do i need other permissions for reading the file?
The called function is copied from google docs.

```
void authExplicit(String jsonPath) throws IOException
    {
        // You can specify a credential file by providing a path to GoogleCredentials.
        // Otherwise credentials are read from the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable.
        GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(jsonPath))
                .createScoped(Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));
        Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).build().getService();

        System.out.println("Buckets:");
        Page<Bucket> buckets = storage.list();
        for (Bucket bucket : buckets.iterateAll()) {
            System.out.println(bucket.toString());
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: `The key.json file is in the same folder as the Activity File` We have no idea where that would be.

Comment: And where should that code run? In an Android app?

Comment: I think it does not matter where you place the file as long as `String jsonPath` has the right value and your app has permission to read it which is often not the case in Android 11+.

Comment: Please remove your comment and place all info in your post. Write a good post to begin with.